# Keyboard not shown even with editText.requestFocus

Tags: android

I am trying to show keyboard when activity is created. But the keyboard is not shown.

I am using `Nexus_5_API_22_x86` emulator

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ex);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ex);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    editText.requestFocus();
}
```

What could be the issue?

I also tried which did not show keyboard at startup time:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ex);
            editText.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    };

    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(tt, 200);

}
```

Comment: What is the config of the emulator? Do you have the "keyboard support" active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did and example to see this and the line that worked for me was this to open

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

and this to close

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

**Edit**:

I tried my example in a Samsung Galaxy S4 (real device)

In the emulator the keyboard won't show

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set requestFocus() first like this

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: yes...I did try that...did not work....I also tried onResume with a timer....did not work